# React js - React-PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with the library "react-pdf". 
I would like to use "word-wrap" to correctly wrap the text, now when the text is too large, insert a "-".

can anyone help me?
thank you all

Comment: What does your code look like? There's probably a configuration for that.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverlflow! What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can disable hyphenation by using [an example from the documentation](https://react-pdf.org/fonts#disabling-hyphenation):

```js
Font.registerHyphenationCallback(word => [word]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define inside of view that work `enter code here`